# Bash beginner: Edit value and add new values

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a group of files (of varying line number) that always finish like this

```
[ molecules ]
; Compound        #mols
Protein_chain_A     1
SOL             12161
```

What I'd like to do using bash is subtract 2 from the value for SOL and add a new line like so within the file (the ideal would be with two tabs between the SOL and CL and their respective values)

```
SOL       12159
CL        2
```

I've tried bits and pieces with awk and sed but it keeps bugging on me. Would it be best to just use something else like Python?

Comment: Oh, I see, by "remove" you mean "subtract".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the language I know the best (Perl in my case). But bash and its tools can serve you well, too:

```
{
    head -n-1 "$file"
    read sol num < <(tail -n1 "$file")
    echo $sol$'\t'$((num-2))
    echo CL$'\t'2
} > "$file".new
mv "$file".new $file
```

Comment: Cheers, does exactly what I wanted! Forgot to mention about the tabs though, anyway simple way I can specify that the spacing between the values with these commands?

Comment: @cc211: Updated. Using `$'\t'` instead of space.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^SOL/ {
        match($0, /^SOL([[:space:]]+)/, a);
        num = $2;
        sub(num "$", num - 2);
        print;
        print "CL" a[1] "2";
        next
    }
    {
        print
    }' inputfile
```

Comment: This attempts to preserve the spacing between the first and second fields.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '$!b;s/\(\S*\)\s*\(\S*\).*/printf "%s\\t\\t%d\\nCL\\t\\t2\\n" "\1" "$((\2-2))"/e' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple one liner

```
awk '{if ( $0 !~ "SOL" ){printf "%s\n",$0}else{printf "%s\t\t%d\nCL\t\t2\n",$1,$2-2}}' filename
```